# Deploying a Visual Studio - SQL Server Application in a Network Enviroment

Tags: vb.net, deployment, sql-server-2008-r2, crystal-reports

I need to run a Student Information Management System on several college devices, knowing that the application was written in VB.Net and connected to a SQL Server 2008 database, but it includes additional references like Crystal Reports (V13.0.4) and DotNet Bar V2.0.

How can I run this application without the need of installing all this software programs (Visual Studio 2010 & SQL Server 2008 R2 & Crystal Report & DotNet Bar) on the client machine first?

All help will be appreciated & thanks in advance :)

Comment: You can put the SQL Server onto a central computer and then just reference it from each device that needs access to it. The other items (except Visual Studio) most likely will have to be installed on the client machines (at least **runtime** components, e.g. Crystal Reports **Runtime** - not the whole designer and everything)

Comment: Thank You @marc_s for your answer first and foremost, but to be honest i can't find a way to reference the SQL Server DB in the client machine, besides how can i get the Run-Time components of the aforementioned components (tools).. i apologize for my lack of knowledge but i desperately need a solution to this issue hence the clients am working on have very low specs. TIA again ^_^